# Query: ventas por mes con condiccion (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Tengo una problemilla, quiza algo sencillo, pero aun no me sale.

Este es el resultado a obtener

[image: Resultado final]

```
 SELECT month(sale_date) as mes, SUM(subtotal) as Totalizado 
 FROM sales 
 WHERE YEAR(sale_date) = '2018' 
 GROUP BY 1 order by 1
```

Este me saca el totalizado global de mis ventas, en sales tengo una columna estado (PAGADA, DEBE o ANULADO), me faltaría listar al lado como columnas al igual que en la imagen, intente hacerlo con case o if pero no tuve éxito.

Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  month(sale_date) as mes,
        SUM(subtotal) as Totalizado,
        SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 'PAGADA' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END)  AS 'PAGADAS',
        SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 'DEBE' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END)    AS 'DEBE',
        SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 'ANULADO' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'ANULADO'
    FROM sales 
    WHERE   YEAR(sale_date) = '2018' 
    GROUP BY month(sale_date) 
    order by month(sale_date)
```

Solo debes condicionar cada suma al estado que corresponda mediante un `CASE`, haciendo, por ejemplo: `SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 'PAGADA' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END)`. Te sugiero que si muestras un Total, muestres todos los subtotales que lo componen, suele generar confusión que estos no terminen sumando, por eso agregué también la columna por `ANULADO`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio!