# Consultar el total de ventas de hoy por campaña, en base a dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas: (ventat, ventap). A las 2 lo que hago es contar la cantidad de ventas que tengo de hoy por determinada campaña, esto lo logro de la siguiente manera:

```
-- Ventas t de hoy
SELECT
 estado,
 COUNT(*) 
 From ventat WHERE 
 fecha = CURDATE()
 AND campana = 'IN' 
 AND estado = 'Digitada'
 GROUP BY estado 

-- ventas p de hoy
SELECT
 estado,
 COUNT(*) 
 From ventap WHERE 
 fecha = CURDATE()
 AND campana = 'IN' 
 AND estado = 'Digitada'
 GROUP BY estado
```

Bueno, dirán, *y si funciona, ¿cuál es el problema?* Realmente lo que quiero es que aparezcan agrupadas por estado las ventas que tiene en este mismo la tabla `ventat` y `ventap`.
Inicialmente planteo el sql de la siguiente manera:

```
 SELECT estado AS s, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)  From ventat WHERE  fecha = CURDATE() AND campana = 'IN'  AND estado = s) AS ventasT,
(SELECT COUNT(*)  From ventap WHERE  fecha = CURDATE() AND campana = 'IN'  AND estado = s) AS ventasP,
(SELECT COUNT(*)  From ventat WHERE  fecha = CURDATE() AND campana = 'IN'  AND estado = s) + (SELECT COUNT(*)  From ventap WHERE  fecha = CURDATE() AND campana = 'IN'  AND estado = s)  AS total
FROM ventat
GROUP BY s
```

Estoy consciente que el total de las 2 subconsultas no es el más eficiente. Por eso acudo a vosotros.

Comparto tambien el Script:

```
CREATE TABLE `ventat` (
  `color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar NOT NULL,
  `campana` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `ventat` (`color`, `id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `campana`, `fecha`, `estado`, `ciudad`) VALUES
('#000', 1, 'Manuel', 'Muñoz', 'IN', '2021-12-23', 'Digitada', 'Bogotá'),
('#000', 2, 'Pedro', 'Martinez', 'IN', '2021-12-23', 'Devuelta', 'Medellín'),
('#000', 3, 'Fabian ', 'Mendoza', 'IN', '2021-12-23', 'Confirmada', 'Cartagena'),
('#000', 4, 'Tereza', 'Gamboa', 'OUT', '2021-12-23', 'Digitada', 'Madrid'),
('#000', 5, 'Nicolas', 'Menendez', 'OUT', '2021-12-23', 'Devuelta', 'Salamanca'),
('#000', 6, 'James', 'Bont', 'OUT', '2021-12-23', 'Confirmada', 'Gijon');
```

Duplicamos los datos pero ahora con el nombre ventap.

Comment: Miren que encontre una respuesta muy pareceda pero aún no doy con el tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176004/query-ventas-por-mes-con-condiccion-mysql?rq=1

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el esquema de las dos tablas? Puedes usar `SHOW CREATE TABLE tabla` para obtenerlo. Nos facilitaría mucho reproducir tu problema y poder comprobar que funciona adecuadamente.

Comment: comparto el script en la pregunta

Comment: @WeizmanCastañeda si la respuesta te fue útil y ya no hay más dudas te agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada,gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T1.Tabla, T1.estado, count(*) as Total
from   
( 
 select estado, "ventat" as Tabla
 from ventat 
 where
  fecha = CURDATE()
  and campana = 'IN' 
  and estado = 'Digitada' 
 union all
 select estado, "ventap" as Tabla 
 from ventap 
 where
  fecha = CURDATE()
  and campana = 'IN' 
  and estado = 'Digitada'
) T1
group by T1.Tabla, T1.estado;
```

Tus dos consultas originales las unimos mediante el **operador de conjunto union all** y ponemos en el **select** un nuevo campo que seria el nombre de cada tabla, sobre esta unión entre las dos tablas hacemos un consulta mas general la cual hará un **group by**  por los **campos Tabla y estado** (campos creados en tu consulta interna) y en el **select** de esta consulta general proyectamos los **campos Tabla y estado** y además, aplicamos la **función de agregación count**, obteniendo de esta forma el total de veces que aparece por cada tabla el estado.

Comment: Bueno, está súper el planteamiento de la query, pero tengo un proglema si combino las 2 subcosultas me trae como resultado 1 en todos los totales.

Comment: Pero si saco el union y una de las subconsultas, cualquiera, probé de ambas formas, funciona perfectamente

Comment: En vez de union pon union all

Comment: Maravilloso hombre eres el mejor. Y si además quisiera sumar los digitados de las 2 tablas, como se replantearía...

Comment: bueno aunque ya trayendo los datos le aplica un record.filter() y listo

Comment: Gracias por participar del foro